# override quantity of new order item in wp_admin (shop_order) page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When the shop owner is adding a new order from WP-Admin I need to override the quantity of the items being added. For the time being I'm hardcoding this value to be 2.

I've tried this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_ajax_order_item', 'VNA_add_item_quantity', 10, 2);
function VNA_add_item_quantity($item, $item_id) {
    $item = $item->get_order()->get_item($item_id, false);
    $item->set_quantity(2);
    $item->apply_changes();
    $item->save();
    $item->get_order()->add_item($item);

    return $item;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't reflect in the order and it continues to show quantity=1 for the newly added item. I'm not able to figure out what is missing. Can someone help?

Note:

1. By default, the `$item` argument that is passed to our function is a new object loaded from DB. So I'm executing following code, so that the `$item` object from the `order->items` collection is used for further processing. (Passing `false` as second param to `get_item()` )

   ```
   $item = $item->get_order()->get_item($item_id, false);
   ```

   Whether I use this code or not, the result is same.
2. At the end I'm adding the `$item` object back to `order` just to overwrite any references. But it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root Cause:**

When we call `$item->get_order()` its internally calling `wc_get_order` which returns a new Order object. So when I'm trying to add the item back to order (using `$item->get_order()->add_item($item);`) its getting added to this new order object and the original order object created/used inside `WC_AJAX::add_order_item()` remains unchanged. That's the reason the changes don't reflect back.

**Solution:**

As suggested @ [Woocommerce, update price when added by admin via wp-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47436147/332188)
, I used the action `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta`. Here we get the reference of the original order object as 3rd param and then we can manipulate it as we want. Those changes get reflected properly.

So here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta', 'VNA_set_item_quantity', 99, 3 );
function VNA_set_item_quantity( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $order_item_id => $order_item_data ) {
        if ( $order_item_id == $item_id ) {

            $qty = 2;

            $order_item_data->set_quantity($qty);
            $order_item_data->set_subtotal($qty * $order_item_data->get_subtotal());
            $order_item_data->set_total($qty * $order_item_data->get_total());

            $order->apply_changes();
            $order->save();
        }
    }
}
```

A weird observation is that once we update the quantity, we also need to update the subtotal and total. Otherwise it starts displaying rate = total / qty.

Example:

If the product cost was 100, it would originally show as:

```
prod name     | rate   | qty    | total
prod123       | 100    | 1      | 100
```

Now if you just change the quantity it starts showing as:

```
prod name     | rate   | qty    | total
prod123       | 50     | 2      | 100
```

So for some reason, it seems that rate is a calculated field instead of total. That's the reason when we update the qty, we also need to update the subtotal and total. That will correctly show it as:

```
prod name     | rate   | qty    | total
prod123       | 100    | 2      | 200
```

Hope this helps someone.